# Images from website not working for server root

Tags: image, ubuntu

I am hosting multiple websites on the same server. Instead of uploading the (same) pictures for each website into individual folders, I would like to make ONE main folder on the server where all websites will get their image from, so I dont end up with duplicates.

I tried everything but cannot seem to get it working. Can anyone help me out?

Hosting on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache2.

My host file:

```
    Alias "/product-image" "/var/www/uploads"

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

So basically what I want is when my SRC goes to:

mysite.com/product-image/ferrari/f1.jpg

it should be served from

/var/www/uploads/ferrari/f1.jpg

Tried multiple tutorials but nothing worked so far.

P.S. when I go to the url `mysite.com/product-image` I would expect to see my upload folder but I see nothing. Instead I get an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /product-image was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at bedrijfskledinggroothandel.nl Port 443

Answer (score 0):

If you have your multiple websites set up as subdomains in your hosting (as I do), each website at run time can only see the files in or below its specific subdirectory - the hosting will put this layer of security in place.

If this is your own server, not externally hosted, the same may well apply but you may perhaps be able to override this element of the configuration (if you want to - to me, the reason for this security layer is to prevent users realising the stuff is in the same place and trying to take advantage of the fact in some way).

You could however get to what I think is your objective by putting a http (not file level) redirect in place (via .htaccess) so that the subdomain interpreted https://my-website.com/Images (or whatever) as https://www.my-main-domain.com/central-image-directory, which would do the trick I think.